# Routing between two sets of coordinate points with plotly, networkx, and osmnx in Python

Tags: python, loops, routes, networkx

I have generated a table that has 4 columns for 2 different sets of points. It contains origin and destination points separated by latitude and longitude coords. I am trying to find all the shortest routes from every origin point to every destination point. This code allows me to find the fastest route from the first origin point to the first destination, and so on, but fails if the sets aren't the same length. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
start_time = time.time()
df['osmnx_geometry'] = df.apply(lambda x: shortestpath(x['o_lat'], x['o_long'], x['d_lat'],
x['d_long'])[0],axis=1 )
df['osmnx_length'] = df.apply(lambda x: shortestpath(x['o_lat'], x['o_long'], x['d_lat'],
x['d_long'])[1],axis=1 )

print("Time taken: ", (time.time() - start_time), "seconds")
```

I also have the function declarations if that helps:

```
def shortestpath(o_lat, o_long, d_lat, d_long):
    
    nearestnode_origin, dist_o_to_onode = ox.nearest_nodes(G, o_lat, o_long, return_dist=True)
    nearestnode_dest, dist_d_to_dnode = ox.nearest_nodes(G, d_lat, d_long, return_dist=True)
    
    #Add up distance to nodes from both o and d ends. This is the distance that's not covered by the network
    dist_to_network = dist_o_to_onode + dist_d_to_dnode
    
    shortest_p = nx.shortest_path(G,nearestnode_origin, nearestnode_dest) 
    
    route = nodes_to_linestring(shortest_p) #Method defined above
    
    # Calculating length of the route requires projection into UTM system. Using 
    inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(32614)
    coordTransform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)
    
    #route.wkt returns wkt of the shapely object. This step was necessary as transformation can be applied 
    
    geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(route.wkt)
   
    geom.Transform(coordTransform)
    length = geom.Length()
    
    #Total length to be covered is length along network between the nodes plus the distance from the O,D points to their nearest nodes
    total_length = length + dist_to_network
    #in metres
    
    return(route, total_length )
```

Comment: You can pass OSMnx's `shortest_path` function lists of origins and destinations to solve in parallel: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.shortest_path

Comment: Lists of different lengths return an error which is where my problem lies

Comment: You didn't provide a reproducible code snippet, with all variables defined and a complete error traceback, so it's impossible to guess what's going on here. But yes, if you're iterating then your lists should be of the same length.

Comment: See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73029281/7321942