# Trying to get an accurate distance of route(in meters) between coordinate points

Tags: python, networking, networkx, osmnx

I am having trouble getting an accurate distance in meters between the coordinate points in my data frame. The data frame has over 300 rows so I won't add that to my question post. I cant figure out what units my length column is displaying in or how to get a length in meters. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is everything in my program except for the data frame.

```
G= ox.graph_from_place('Grand Forks, North Dakota')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)
```

```
def nodes_to_linestring(path):
    coords_list = [(G.nodes[i]['x'], G.nodes[i]['y']) for i in path ]
    #print(coords_list)
    line = LineString(coords_list)
    
    return(line)

def shortestpath(o_lat, o_long, d1_lat, d1_long):
    
    nearestnode_origin, dist_o_to_onode = ox.nearest_nodes(G, o_lat, o_long, return_dist=True)
    nearestnode_dest, dist_d_to_dnode = ox.nearest_nodes(G, d1_lat, d1_long, return_dist=True)
    
    #Add up distance to nodes from both o and d ends. This is the distance that's not covered by the network
    dist_to_network = dist_o_to_onode + dist_d_to_dnode
    
    shortest_p = nx.shortest_path(G,nearestnode_origin, nearestnode_dest) 
    
    route = nodes_to_linestring(shortest_p) #Method defined above
    
    
    inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(4236)
    outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(32614)
    coordTransform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)
    
    
   
    geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(route.wkt)
   
    #geom.Transform(coordTransform)
    length = geom.Length()
    
    #Total length to be covered is length along network between the nodes plus the distance from the O,D points to their nearest nodes
    total_length = length + dist_to_network
    #in metres
    
    return(route,total_length )
```

```
start_time = time.time()

df['osmnx_geometry'] = df.apply(lambda x: shortestpath(x['o_long'], x['o_lat'], x['d1_long'], x['d1_lat'])[0],axis=1 )
df['osmnx_length'] = df.apply(lambda x: shortestpath(x['o_long'], x['o_lat'], x['d1_long'], x['d1_lat'])[1],axis=1 )

print("Time taken: ", (time.time() - start_time), "seconds")
```

Comment: It looks like you have latitude and longitude.  Those are going to be in degrees.  It's not trivial to compute the distance between two lat/long points, because the size of a degree of longitude varies depending on your latitude.  `osmnx` includs functions to do that.

Comment: It looks like you want to utilize the Haversine formula for finding distances on a sphere.  This link [Haversine](https://community.esri.com/t5/coordinate-reference-systems-blog/distance-on-a-sphere-the-haversine-formula/ba-p/902128) probably would work as it has a solution written in python.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler and faster way to accomplish this. It sums up the network distance and the distances between your origin/destination points and their nearest nodes for each row in your OD matrix DataFrame.

```py
import osmnx as ox
import pandas as pd

# get a fully connected graph so all paths are solvable
G = ox.graph_from_place('Grand Forks, North Dakota')
G = ox.utils_graph.get_largest_component(G, strongly=True)

# create a DataFrame with random lat and lng columns then convert to OD matrix
# 20 origins x 20 destinations = a 400 row OD matrix
points = ox.utils_geo.sample_points(ox.get_undirected(G), n=20).reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([points.x, points.y], axis=1)
df.columns = ['lng', 'lat']
od = pd.merge(df.assign(key=0), df.sample(len(df)).assign(key=0), on='key', suffixes=[1, 2]).drop('key', axis=1)

# get lists of nearest origin/destination nodes and their distances from the points
origs, orig_dists = ox.nearest_nodes(G, od['lng1'], od['lat1'], return_dist=True)
dests, dest_dists = ox.nearest_nodes(G, od['lng2'], od['lat2'], return_dist=True)

# solve all shortest paths in parallel then calculate their distances along network
paths = ox.shortest_path(G, origs, dests, weight='length', cpus=None)
od['net_dist'] = [sum(ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(G, path, attribute='length')) for path in paths]

# total distance = network distance + distance from origin/destination points to their nearest nodes
od['orig_dist'] = orig_dists
od['dest_dist'] = dest_dists
od['total_dist'] = od[['net_dist', 'orig_dist', 'dest_dist']].sum(axis=1)
od.head()
```